# How to get all the documents within a collection that have the highest value for a certain integer field out of all documents in the collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore collection called "players", and each document within "players" contains an integer field called "score". I'd like to get all of the documents within the "players" collection that have the highest value for "score" out of all the documents in the "players" collection. In other words, I'm trying to find all of the documents within the "players" collection who are tied for 1st in terms of score. How do I accomplish this? I have found a way to get the highest "score" in the collection, but how do I get all of the documents who have the highest "score"? Thanks!

Comment: please provide at lease a input example, an output expected, and posibbly what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with a single query (at least not reliably, and without overshooting the minimum number of documents you want).  What you will have to do is request multiple documents (perhaps limiting to 10), then filter out the ones that do not have a tie for the highest score.  If all of the documents share the high score, you will need to use [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) to request the next batch, and again filter out the documents that you don't want.